# Why are the crew wearing anti-contamination suits?

Tags: westworld-tv

In *Westworld* Episode 7 the working crew comes into the Westworld wearing some kind of anti-contamination suits to retrieve Clementine Pennyfeather, while all the other hosts are frozen

But we saw working crew coming on Westworld many times before without any suit, so why are they wearing them in this particular situation ?

Comment: Good question.  Are there other times we see crew working "on set" rather than behind the scenes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a contamination issue since 'killed' and 'deactivated' hosts are interacted with by the human technicians in a variety of clothing.

**However**, while *in the park itself*, the hosts are programmed *not to see, notice or recognise anything that they would not know of in their supposed storyline/environment.*

Since the hazmat suits are not of the 'in park' time period, the wearers would not be visible to the hosts and would be ignored. It's also possible that hosts are *specifically programmed* to ignore people wearing such suits.

Which is why it so shocking when Maeve *does* start remembering them.

Comment: To add to this, it seems like the full hazmat suit is mostly for recovering hosts after big massacres where lots of host bodily fluids are strewn about. Even without a specific biohazard threat, just simple hygiene/sanitation would recommend a protective suit. The more biological hosts are shown to at least drink (I think some were shown eating) so there could be spoiled food material/solid waste, plus guests deposited... ahh, fluids as well. Unsuited techs were mostly seen around hosts on slabs where they were cleaned up a bit.